# Display sum of timestamps as 00:01:26 instead of 126

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working on a site where workers' hours are calculated based on when they clock in (start) and clock out (end). end - start = total. I have successfully computed the difference between the start and end. The start, end, and total are inserted into a DB. The "Shift total" comes from the SQL SUM of total in the db. The last foreach statement is the code in question. I want to format the "Shift total" as 00:00:00 so that it would show as 00:01:26 instead of 126. I have tried ". $row['SUM(total)'] + '00:00:00' . " but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how I should go about this? Thanks in advance. I pasted the results first then the code.

**____start____________end____________total**

```
10:44:46 AM     10:44:49 AM     00:00:03
10:50:12 AM     10:50:14 AM     00:00:02
10:50:27 AM     10:50:32 AM     00:00:05
11:12:02 AM     11:13:18 AM     00:01:16
                 Shift total --> 126

$sql3 = "SELECT date, startTime, endTime, total FROM timeSheet WHERE userName='$user_name'";
$sql4 = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM timeSheet WHERE userName='$user_name'";
echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
     <th>date</th>
     <th>start</th>
     <th>end</th>
     <th>total</th>
     </tr>";
foreach ($conn->query($sql3) as $row) { 
    $start = explode (" ", $row['startTime']);
    $end = explode(" ", $row['endTime']);
    if ($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $start[1] = '0';
    }else if ($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
        $end[1] = '0';
    }else{        
        $start[1] = date("h:i:s A", strtotime($start[1]));
        $end[1] = date("h:i:s A", strtotime($end[1]));
    }

    echo "<tr>
     <th>" . $row['date'] . "</th>
     <th>" . $start[1] . "</th>
     <th>" . $end[1] . "</th>
     <th>" . $row['total'] . "</th>
     </tr>";
}
foreach ($conn->query($sql4) as $row) { 
    echo "<tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>SUM</th>
            <th>". $row['SUM(total)']  . "</th>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: MySQL. Sql Server. Pick one.

Comment: The term, "sum of timestamps" does not make sense.  If you can't explain what it means, your entire approach might be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function:

```
$sql4 = "SELECT TIME(SUM(total)) AS totalSum FROM timeSheet WHERE userName='$user_name'";
//....
foreach ($conn->query($sql4) as $row) { 
echo "<tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>SUM</th>
        <th>". $row['totalSum'] . "</th>
    </tr>";
}
```

---

**hint:**
actually you don't need the `total` column in your database. You can use i.e

```
SELECT date, startTime, endTime, TIMEDIFF(startTime, endTime) AS total FROM timeSheet WHERE userName='$user_name'"
```

and

```
SELECT TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(startTime, endTime))) AS totalSum FROM timeSheet WHERE userName='$user_name'
```

for further information have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff